# Date not in correct format

Tags: c#

I have a function that checks for null values then converts dates if they are not null
the below function just had "08/09/13" sent to it (English format) and i got "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

anyone help me as to why? do i need to tell the something somewhere is uses English format?

Thanks

```
public static DateTime DateTimeCheck(object objDateTime)
        {
            if (objDateTime == null || objDateTime == "")
                return default(DateTime);
            return Convert.ToDateTime(objDateTime);

        }
```

Comment: What is your culture?

Comment: where do i set my culture for the entire website?

Comment: What is the value of `objDateTime` you pass to `DateTimeCheck`? Your code work to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you passed an `object` as a parameter instead of `string` first of all.

Try this instead;

```
public static DateTime DateTimeCheck(object objDateTime)
{
   ...
   return DateTime.ParseExact(objDateTime.ToString(),"dd/MM/yy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);    
}
```

Of course, this throws exception if your object is not formatted same as with `"dd/MM/yy"`.

Take a look at;

- [`Custom Date and Time Format Strings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You might be in a different culture with a different default date format. However you can use [ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) to parse in the expected format. For example:

```
 CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
 DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact("25/12/82","dd/MM/yy",provider);
```

Comment: is this set per item? or can i set it for the whole site?

Comment: Per item. If you want to set for the whole site or page you're going to have to switch the culture, for example see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.ASPX

Answer (score 1):

You can use the overloaded method that accepts the culture information:

```
Convert.ToDateTime(o, new CultureInfo("en-Gb"));
```

To get or set the current culture you can use:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this not what you are looking for but that's how to be sure that some object has date time value in it something like that :

```
    public static DateTime DateTimeCheck(object objDateTime)
    {
        DateTime dateTime ;
        if (objDateTime != null)
        {
            if (DateTime.TryParse(objDateTime.ToString(), out dateTime))
            {
                return Convert.ToDateTime(objDateTime);
            }
        }

        return default(DateTime);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DateTime.ParseExact((string)objDateTime,"dd/MM/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```